# QFileInfo owner & group are empty

Tags: c++, qt, file

Here's my slot :

```
void MainWindow::writeOnFile(const QString &path)
{
    // Get info files :
    QFileInfo fileInfo(path);
    QString name = fileInfo.fileName();
    QString lastModif = fileInfo.lastModified().toString();
    QString owner = fileInfo.owner();
    QString group = fileInfo.group();
    QString lastRead = fileInfo.lastRead().toString();
    QString created = fileInfo.created().toString();


    // Write on Logs :
    QString filename = "C:\\Users\\Sherlock\\Desktop\\logs.txt";
    QFile file ( filename );
    if ( file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text) )
    {
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        stream << "The file " << name
               << " was first created on " << created
               << ", was last read on " << lastRead
               << " and was last modified on " << lastModif
               << ". The owner is " << owner
               << ". The group is " << group
               << endl;
    }
}
```

And here's my output :

> The file younes.txt was first created on lun. août 17 19:40:34 2015,
>   was last read on lun. août 17 19:40:34 2015 and was last modified on
>   mar. août 18 00:21:51 2015. The owner is . The group is

As you can see, the **owner** and the **group** are not displayed.

Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: What OS are you running? What is the file system of the disk of `younes.txt`?

Comment: The OS is : `Windows 8` and the File System is `NTFS`

Comment: NTFS doesn't have the unix-like concept of ownership and groups. These members only make sense on unix filesystems.

Comment: @Kuba Ober : So how can I retrieve the owner and/or the group of the file given that I can see them in Files > Properties ? Thank you.

Comment: You don't see a group as a file property, perhaps you see the group of the owner (now you're asking for an attribute of a user entity, not of the file, so that doesn't belong in `QFileInfo` but some yet-unimplemented `QSystemUserInfo`). Owner itself is another story - perhaps this is not implemented yet.

Comment: @Kuba Ober : Oh, my bad :-( On the other hand, I couldn't find anything about `QSystemUserInfo` in Qt documentation (or Google).

Comment: @Sherlock That's because it's not implemented yet :)

Answer (score 1):

> On Windows [...] an empty string is returned.

So, it is documented that `group()` acts that way.

Comment: I know, same goes for owner(). I posted this to know if there might be a tip/hack to get this information.

Comment: @Sherlock The group() will never be implemented, since on Windows, file objects are groupless. A group is a property of a user, not of a file. The `owner()` appears not to be implemented either, feel free to file that as a feature request in Qt bugtracker (assuming no such request exists yet), and feel free to submit a patch to Qt to implement it!